# Unable to retrieve the values in a website using Selenium Web Driver on C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When practicing wring a simple Unit Test on Selenium (Web Driver) on C#, I've faced one issue related to retrieve the values in the text box. The issue seems to be very basic but I tried different ways to solve it but no luck.

The simple website has URL `http://www.donethedeal.com`. After clicking on ADD TO CART and then, VIEW CART, there is a field named Quantity. To retrieve the value in this field, my code written in C# is as below:

```
Assert.AreEqual("1", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div/input")).Text);
```

I can't figure why this doesn't work. It always shows unable to locate the element. The Xpath I input in this code line is retrieved by right-click on Quantity box > Inspect > highlight the text and copy Xpath on Chrome.

```
//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div/input
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `value` attribute using `GetAttribute`, the "1" is stored there

```
Assert.AreEqual("1", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div/input")).GetAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: Super! Your explanation works like magic. Thank you very much! :)